# What is the name of the protruding shaft on a single-handle bath faucet?

Tags: plumbing

Anybody know the name of this part? It goes on the single handle ball faucet and then you can screw the knob on it. Mine is broken and don't know where to buy this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like this to me: https://www.globalindustrial.com/p/delta-stainless-steel-ball-straight-broach-pack-of-6

Comment: That looks exactly like my Delta brand kitchen sink valve. For my sink, you can surprisingly get all of the parts at the local big box store. The hard part for me was figuring out the model # of the valve to get the compatible parts. Once I figured out the model, I was able to find a parts diagram with part numbers for each component.

Answer (score 1):

You would buy a replacement cartridge assembly from the manufacturer of the valve, or a dealer who carries them.
Shower valves are all of proprietary design, made of proprietary parts with proprietary names. You will rarely, if ever, find component parts of such valves, such as yours, for sale by anybody, except sometimes replaceable seals.